# $L^\infty$, $L^p$ question

Tags: lp-spaces

Suppose $f \in L^0$. I read that for a general measure space, if $\mu(X)<\infty$, then we cannot have that both  $||f||_\infty< \infty$ and $||f||_p=\infty$ for every $p\in (0,\infty)$, but if $\mu(X)=\infty$, then we can find an $f$ such that this statement is true.
I'm not sure how to show this for the finite case and am having trouble thinking of an example of a function $f$ for the infinite case such that $||f||_\infty< \infty$ and $||f||_p=\infty$ for every $p\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: What is $L^0$? Is it $L^\infty$?

Comment: $L^0=\{f:f$ is a measurable function from $X$ to a field $\mathbb{k}\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For the first case, you can actually show that

$$||f||_p \leq ||f||_\infty \mu(X)^{1/p}$$

if $\mu(X) < \infty$. For the second one, consider $X = \mathbb R$ with the Lebesgue measure. Can you found a bounded positive function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ so that

$$\int_\mathbb R f dx = + \infty?$$

(Don't think too hard)

Comment: Yes, for example, let $f\equiv 1$, then? :) (Don't think too hard) @John I like this sentence.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! So for a general measure space, if $\mu(X)=\infty$, we could just make $f$ the characteristic function of $X$?

Comment: @user192119: Exactly.